# How do I keep the precision in my Python function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, decimal, precision

All,

I am working on a simple function which accepts a value and calculates the minimum number of coins to distribute based on the value. I've been using 1.20 as my amount. Thus, I should get back 6 coins - 2 quarters and 2 dimes. For simplicity sake, I am only showing the quarters portion of the code. When I run my sample code below, the precision for the operation **amount = amount - quarters** is correct through the first two iterations, however, by the third, the amount changes to 0.44999999999999996.

- 1st iteration: 0.95
- 2nd iteration: 0.7
- 3rd iteration: 0.44999999999999996

Do you know why this happening and how I fix this issue? I've tried using decimal.Decimal and changing the precision. I don't want to fix only the formatting but would like to fix the actual amount as that is crucial to how many coins are counted.

```
#amount for testing
amount = 1.20

#coins
quarter = 0.25

def min_coins(amount):
    count_quarter = 0
    while amount >= quarter:
        amount = amount - quarter
        print(amount)
        count_quarter += 1

min_coins(amount)
```

Comment: Calculate amounts in whole pennies.  Don't use floating point at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [John Gordon notes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58068897/how-do-i-keep-the-precision-in-my-python-function/58069108#comment102533600_58068897), for monetary applications, you don't want to use floating point at all. Either use the `decimal.Decimal` module to perform decimal accurate calculations, or perform your math with `int` pennies, instead of `float` dollars; if the API must accept `float` dollars, convert the values on entry, and convert back on return. For your code, the `int` pennies approach would look like:

```
#amount for testing
amount = 1.20

#coins
quarter = 25

def min_coins(amount):
    amount = round(amount * 100)  # Convert from float dollars to int pennies
    count_quarter = 0
    while amount >= quarter:
        amount -= quarter
        print(amount)  # Or print('{:.2f}'.format(amount / 100)) if necessary
        count_quarter += 1

min_coins(amount)
```